# Google app engine jpa data Retrieval Exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I am newbie to Google app engine. I have written a simple webapps with JPA to store and retrieve data. My program successfully inserting the data in the database (JPA) (data show in the Datastore page of google app engine) but at the time of retrieval I am getting an "java.lang.NullPointerException" error.

My program

```
package com.alokpanda;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SaveAndView extends HttpServlet {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setAddress(address);

        em.persist(user);


        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        response.setContentType("plain/text");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        EntityManagerFactory emf2 = null;
        EntityManager em2 = null;
        Query query = null;
        List<User> list = null;
        try {
        emf2 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print(e);
        }
        try {
        em2 = emf2.createEntityManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print("em problem :"+e);
        }
        try {


        query = em2.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u", User.class);
        list = query.getResultList();


        if(list != null) {
            out.print(list);
        } else {
            out.print("null");
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print(e+" : ");
            out.print(query+" : ");
            out.print(list+" : ");
            out.print(em);
        }


    }

}
```

Program output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException : SELECT u FROM User u : null : org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager@161b59f3
```

Comment: I probably won't be able to help since I don't use JPA, but just a friendly suggestion that including the stack trace could be helpful to someone who can. Also, can you define better what you mean by "at the time of retrieval"? The code you posted doesn't look like it's doing any retrieving.

Comment: why would you create a new EMF ? you already have one. What is null in the NullPointerException you mention? the stack trace should tell you this ... but you don't seem to have debugged that far ...